# Hide print_r result in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

`Print_r` function is usually to output the array result, but I want to hide the result it should be seen on the browser is there a certain way to hide it?

The reason why I want to hide it is, because I just realized that to output and sort a big array outside a loop is impossible to do only when I output it with print_r function in the loop and then to sort it and order in a table outside the loop.

Here is a sample

```
$arr = array('jow', 'jack');//Big array,
$arr1 = array();
foreach($arr as $val){
    $arr1[] = $val;
    print_r($arr1); // hide it here
}
//Order it and sort it outside the loop.
```

Comment: You could wrap the output in HTML comments: `<!-- insert stuff here -->` but if it's sensitive data, make sure it's not visible on production sites

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What is your goal? What code have you written?

Comment: Show us your code - the `print_r()` will **not** be helping you to achieve what you want, and will not be doing what you think it is

Comment: I think its very clear as other had answered me.

Comment: Just because others have answered 1 particular part of the question (the hiding output from the browser) does not mean that the whole question is well written

Comment: so basically you print this data, probably in a javascript array or something, and then use javascript to sort it in tables?

Comment: So this sums it up? "I use print_r on this array data to fill in data structures my client javascript uses; this data is then sorted by me also using javascript. This works/Doesn't work (together with any errors or unexpected behaviour you get). I would like to hide this data since currently it's shown."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
echo "<!-- \n".print_r($value, TRUE)."\n-->\n\n";
```

Check your code in your browser through Right Click.

Comment: Thank you, Is there something i should be able to hide also from the code or I have to do it with AJAX?

Comment: ajax isn't the solution for everything

Comment: So what do suggest I should do to hide the arrays also from the view?

Answer (score 3):

```
ob_start();
print_r($value);
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **CSS** to "hide" any output from the browser.

```
echo "<div style='display: none;'>".print_r($arr1)."</div>";
```

and later on you can show by changing '**display: none**' to '**display: block**'.